# avatars disappearing in aframe

Tags: aframe, avatar

In aframe js, when one of the avatars move too close to another avatar, the other avatar seems to disappear first partially and when too close to the avatar it's disappearing completely. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the camera of the avatar moving "too close" is entering inside the avatar model, which might be not textured on the inside causing it to "disappear".
Try playing around with the FOV to see if this is the case, if so, you may want to add some kind of collision system to your scene.